# Generte resource ID at runtime?

Tags: android

I am writing a custom preference with a seek bar, so far it works, except for one problem the ID of my seek bar is defined in XML, so when I try to use 2 of my custom prefernces and then I update the Seek Bar I cannot distinguish between the two.

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.PreferenceSeekBar);
```

Is there a way to generate a custom Resource ID at runtime?
Or perhaps another way to solve this?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: What is `view` in your code listing?

Comment: @CommonsWare: on the onBind ovverriden method of custom preference, you are passed a View view, which contains all the views on the current preference activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on the onBind ovverriden method of custom preference, you are passed a View view, which contains all the views on the current preference activity.

There is no `onBind()` method on `Preference`. There *is* an `onBindView()` method. However, the `View` passed to `onBindView()` is whatever `View` you returned from `onCreateView()`, or the `View` inflated from your specified layout file if you went that route. It is not the entire activity.

Make sure you are calling `findViewById()` on the widget that was created for your `Preference`, not something with broader scope.

Also, bear in mind that `PreferenceActivity` is a `ListActivity`. If your custom `Preference` scrolls off the screen, its `View` may be handed to another instance of your custom `Preference` for recycling.

Comment: Yea, I know even considering that the affect I am getting is that both Seek Bars are moving when I move only one. Which doesn't make sense considering the View passed to me does not contain both of the seek bars

Comment: @Jason: This problem sounds really familiar, though I do not recall the solution.

Comment: shame, I have been wracking at this for a while, if I create a copy of the custom prefernce class and use that - it solves it, suggesting a mixed reference but i cannot find any.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit future comers:

Tag your view with setTag() and reference it baack with findViewWithTag();

source: [Inflate a TableRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293732/inflate-a-tablerow)