# Reserve a "slot" in a layout XML file for a dynamically created button?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I have one (and only one) UI element which isn't referenced in the XML layout file.

That element is a button, instantiated and returned at run-time by a 3rd party library (i.e. I don't have control over that).

My problem is that I would like some of the elements (TextViews) in the XML layout file to be placed relative to **that button**, using `RelativeLayout`.

Is it possible to "reserve an empty slot" in the XML layout file for that button such that I can do something like the following?

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_text_under_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_dynamically_created_button"
        android:text="" />
```

Alternatively, if I were to set the layout at run-time using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule()`, what would be the ID of that dynamically created button, if it has no reference at all in the XML layout file?

For example, in the following call:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.btn_dynamically_created_button);
```

What would I put instead of `R.id.btn_dynamically_created_button`?

**Update**: Thanks to the answer below, I created a place holder like this:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btn_dynamically_created_button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

The challenge now is: How to associate the returned object from getDynamicallyCreatedButton() (returned object is subclass of `LinearLayout`, *not* `Button`), with `R.id.btn_dynamically_created_button`?

EDIT: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058904/generte-resource-id-at-runtime) seem to address a similar issue, but I am not sure that I understand the solution offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

1. Put a LinearLayout with width/height set to wrap-content, horizontal orientation and zero padding as the placeholder.
2. Orient all the other things to that LinearLayout.
3. When its time to put the button, simply stick it into the LinearLayout.

See if that works for you.

EDIT: attempt at a short example:

The layout (suitably shortened): you can place other components relative to the LinearLayout with id *LinearLayout01*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="2sp" android:layout_marginBottom="2sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" style="@style/SimpleButtonBar" android:layout_below="@+id/rootlayout" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:fillViewport="true">
                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/detaillayout">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code (for example, this would go in `onCreate`): fetch your button (you need to make sure it has the right Context, but I figure you're doing that alright), fetch the LinearLayout, create a layout parameters object and stick your button into the LinearLayout.

Button b = getButton(); // retrieve your button somehow

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
l.addView(b, lp);
```

Comment: Can you provide a short code example? It is hard for me to see how I can "stick it" without and actual R.id. Thanks. +1.

Comment: Edited my response to include the 5-minute sample. A little ugly, but captures the essence.

Comment: This works very well, thank you! Another +1 and accept. :) BTW, I tried to "cheat" the system by calling b.setId(R.id.btn_dynamically_created_button) but it didn't work for me for some reason. Even if it worked, your solution is much more elegant and probably safer.

Comment: Glad to know it worked. The issue with setting the ID is that if you're using an XML layout file the LayoutInflater won't know what to do if all the View objects can't be instantiated at the same time. If you were setting up the entire thing in code then that would probably work just fine.